# Memory deallocation in the Singleton pattern in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, singleton

I'm trying to understand memory deallocation when using the Singleton pattern in C++.

All examples that I found that make use of `new` don't explicitly use `delete`, which to me would mean memory leaks.

Why don't they use `delete`?

Is it because by definition we only have one instance of the singleton which, together with its dynamically allocated memory, will just be deleted once the program terminates?

Comment: Yeah I think this is right. As long as you never change the instance of the singleton, you can just rely on it being cleared down at termination.

Comment: Your singleton is destroyed when the program exits. When the program exits all memory is returned to the operating system, so there is no memory leak.

Comment: You could explicitly add a step to do it at the end of your program if you wanted, but I think most devs can't be bothered to be honest.

Comment: However if your singleton needs a destructor to release resources (say a database connection) then it is important that you call that destructor. So your examples would not be good for this kind of singleton.

Comment: Objects allocated with `new` are **not** destroyed when the program exits without a `delete`. Cleanup actions in destructor are not performed. Yes, memory leaks.

Comment: Depends on the context. `std::unique_ptr<Singleton> instance{new Singleton};` doesn't need explicit `delete`. Anyway, concrete answer requires a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of a nature of Singleton.

The most common use of Singleton as opposed to an ordinary global is to ensure it would work when called from other globals and file-level static objects.

Both initialization and destruction sequences of file-level globals are undetermined for different translation units, it is some time period before and after `main()`, respectively. For example, when a global object calls, say, `theLog.log("starting thisGlobal");`, where theLog is just another global, theLog can be uninitialized yet, so for such logging we need a Singleton: when we call the static function to get our log object, this object is constructed regardless of when it is called (the rule of first pass initialization of function-level statics).

Now, what can happen if we delete that static object? And where can we delete it? We can do it in the end of `main()`, but that defies the purpose: our Singleton would be deleted when the destructors of other globals call it. We can delete in one of these destructors of globals, after `main()`, but for globals the order of destruction is as indeterminate as the order of construction, we cannot ensure that exactly that object would be the last destructor, and he can safely delete our Singleton.

Compilers are allowed to defer the initialization in some circumstances, and there are non-standard ways to determine the sequence of initialization/destruction of globals, but if we use this, we don't need Singletons. Just make a global object of that class the first to init, the last to end.

So either we can't destroy the singleton, or we don't need a Singleton at all.

As of memory leaks -- it depends on how you define a leak. Since you allocate this memory only once, it hardly distinguishable from your static memory. False positives by leak detectors usually can be suppressed.